# Parse the css class name that must start and end with specific string jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am just starting to use jsoup and I want to extract the class which has regex like 'start nav.*base' in jsoup. Then I want to get the href. In jsoup, regex is not necessary to use it. So how can I get the tag like

```
<li class="start nav-fruit-more level-top base">
    <a class="level-top" title="All Fruits" href="url link">Fruit</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) `[attr~=regex]` to select elements with attribute values that match the regular expression .

The regex for a string that starts with `start nav` and ends with `base` is `^start(\s)*nav.* base$` , so you can try to use :

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
  System.out.println(doc.select("[class~=^start(\\s)*nav.* base$]").first());
```